# URLResource in drools, not authenticating

Tags: drools

This is regarding drools.

I am trying to access  an URL which has basic authentication. 
I am using the following code, but still getting 401 error. Please help.

```
          String urlString =  "testurl"; 
          URL url = new URL(urlString); 
          UrlResource urlResource = (UrlResource)ResourceFactory.newUrlResource(url);
           urlResource.setBasicAuthentication("enabled"); 
          urlResource.setUsername("admin"); 
          urlResource.setPassword("admin"); 
          knowledgeAgent.applyChangeSet(ResourceFactory.newUrlResource(url));
```

Comment: Can you access the same URL in a browser with same auth?

Answer (score 1):

You need enable admin to read pgk.

Do it in guvnor (http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/) -> Admin -> User permission -> open admin row, and add admin permission.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)